# Run a script if a 3D app is started and stopped on Windows

Tags: windows, powershell, automation, 3d-graphics

I am looking for a mechanism on how to detect if such app is started and stopped and run scripts (powershell or arbitrary app) based on that.

To clarify, by 3D app I mean anything from a game to Blender to Video editor, anything that would use GPU or require low latency/high responsiveness.

So far I looked into Task Scheduler which has an option to trigger a task when an event in Event Log is created - but I did not find any entries that are specific to starting a 3D app. Maybe something can be enabled to create such entries in Event Log?

I also looked into Alarms on MSI Afterburner, but again, I fail to see a way to recognize 3D apps running.

Comment: Are you using an nvidia gpu by chance?

Comment: @Narzard yes, does that make things "easier"?